# how to save posts content in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am looking for advice on how the save long post contents in asp.net. What i mean is that i have a personal website (blog alike) in which i write some code snippets and tutorials. every post got header, tag, date and the content itself. right now i am saving all in mssql table  but i am not sure this is the right way to do it, because the content of the post can get very long and i know that sql has a limit of 4000 chars (im using nvarchar as the type of the column). so i thought about saving the post content as usercontrol(.ascx) but from searching it looks too much complicated to create usercontrol on the fly and save it as a file.
so i need your advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in SQL which removes the limit.

Comment: yes i can do so, but do you think saving it in a table it's the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at a "Document Database" such as [RavenDB](http://www.ravendb.net/).